# Accessing sqlserver via Windows Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I am trying to access SQLserver database via my Azure account. This is because I didnt find a appropriate Database client for my Mac(Sierra) to connect to the SQLserver DB. 
I encounter a firewall error when i try to query the database in the Query editor[Query editor in Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHyPP.png). Can someone help on this?
 *IP is configured to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduce your error:
[image]

We should modify **SQL SERVER** **Firewall** settings, change Allow assess to Azure services to **ON**. Then we can use Query Editor.

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks Jason Ye -MSFT

Comment: @SweT If it helps, please mark it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited. thanks.

Comment: @SweT Please don't forget to mark it as an answer, thanks, we can follow this link to mark it.https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Did .Thanks for the help